# Cannot change color of thumbnail border and button to transparent

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am a newbie and am using a template for a web design class I am taking. I cannot change the color of the top menu bar or change the color of the thumbnail border to transparent either. I've attached the code relevant to this question as well as a screenshot of what I am currently seeing.

Any help with this is appreciated, thank you!

[image]

```css
body {
    background-image: url("../img/yellowcrinkle.jpg")
    
}

header {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0);
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0);
}

.header {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0);
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0); 
}

.grid-container {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0);
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0); 
}

.top-bar{
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0);
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0); 
}

.top-bar-left{
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0);
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0); 
}

.top-bar-right{
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0);
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0);  
}

.menu {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0);
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0); 
}

menu {
    background-color: transparent;
    background: transparent; 
}

a:link {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0);
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0); 
    color: #1D0A0A;
}

a {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0);
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0); 
}

h3 {
    font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, "sans-serif";
}



p {
    font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, "sans-serif";
}

li {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0);
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0); 
    font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, "sans-serif";
}

ul {
    background-color: transparent;
}

button {
    color: transparent;
}

.thumbnail {
    background-color: transparent;
    
}
```

```html
<header class="grid-container">
  <div class="top-bar">
      <img src="img/headerimage.png" alt=""/>
        <div class="top-bar-left">
            <ul class="menu">  
          </ul>
    </div>
        <div class="top-bar-right">
            <ul class="menu">
                <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="resources.html">Resources</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
  </div>
</header>

 <article class="grid-container">
        <div class="grid-x grid-margin-x" id="content">
            <div class="medium-9 cell">
                <div class="blog-post">
            
                    <img class="thumbnail" src="img/aboutme.png">
                    <p>Howdy!</p>
                 
                </div>
                <div class="blog-post">
                 
                    <img class="thumbnail" src="img/philosophy.png">
                    <p></p>
                   
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="medium-3 cell" data-sticky-container>
                <div class="sticky" data-sticky data-anchor="content">
                    <h4>Categories</h4>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="gallery.html">Design</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Typography</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Color</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Animations</a></li>
                    </ul>
                   
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
       
    </article>
```

Comment: I can't really see much of the page, as almost everything is transparent (and this is only part of the page without art and such), however looking at the code, im fairly sure your problem will come from the fact that you're setting both
`background-color` and `background` in many of your CSS blocks, and not in all of them.

Comment: I'm not sure if setting both is encouraged in your class for some reason ? If not then i'd recommend removing the `background` ones, and keeping the `background-color` ones. Alternatively , you could also keep them but then also do the same for the later CSS blocks (like .thumbnail and .ul which only have 1 of the 2)

Answer (score 0):

So with the top menu bar you have to change this:

```
.menu {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

To this:

```
.menu {
  background-color: transparent; 
}
```

That should make your top menu bar transparent.

When it comes to the Thumbnail border, I don't have a solution for that because it seems like you are using some template similar to Bootstrap and stuff which means you'll have to go through the Docs of whatever template you are using to try and find a solution there and get rid of that border.

There are usually clear guidelines that show you how to customize the template you'll be using so go through that.